# Looping through html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that has a table and a small form. The table has some data on questionnaires. I am trying to use `jquery` to loop through the table, checking if a condition is met, then adding it to the correct field of the form. The problem I have is that the forms are not created by me so I cant match them to set `id's`. So i need to get the `field_id` from `relate`, and the `answer` inserting into that `location`. Im new to Jquery and js. This is what I came up with.

html

```
<div align="left">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <td>Question</td>
            <td>Answer</td>
            <td>Relates to</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>Random question 1</td>
                <td>Random answer 1</td>
                <td>add to variable form field</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Random question 2</td>
                <td>Random answer 2</td>
                <td>add to a different form field</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="variable id that could be matched with element of table">
```

main.js

```
table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
    var $mylists = $('#' + relate)    
    $mylists.html('');
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
        label = $tds.eq(0).text(),
        relate = $tds.eq(1).text(),
        answer = $tds.eq(2).text();
    $('<span></span>').text(answer).appendTo($mylists);
});
```

Comment: Post the relevant HTML as well please.

Comment: My guess is you want something like this... `$mylists.html('');'` at the top, before  `var $tds` then easiest is to append spans with answers: `$('<span></span>').text(answer).appendTo($mylists);` if $mylists is an `input` field, then it's something different. You need the `val` jQuery function.

Comment: You seem to be using the variable `relate` before it has been declared, thus it will be undefined.

Comment: Edited my question. @Eli Gassert, is that what you meant as im still not getting anything in my text boxes. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: You're using an *undefined* `relate` variable therefore `$mylists` will not return any jQuery element Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a single input that you want to append values you, you need to set the `val` of the input. And since you want to create that single input value from multiple other values (answers), you need to loop through, get all your answers, then combine them into a single value. Something like this:

```
var $mylists = $('#' + relate);
$mylists.val('');
var answers = [];
table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
        label = $tds.eq(0).text(),
        relate = $tds.eq(1).text(),
        answer = $tds.eq(2).text();
    answers.push(answer);
});

// at this point, answers contains an array of all your individual answer values.
// decision time: what do you want to do with them?
// in this example, I join them together in a comma-delimited list.

$mylists.val( answers.join(', ') );
```

Comment: Sorry my examples bad. There will be multiple inputs depending on form a user creates.

Comment: Then you need to provide a better example. The answer I provided fits the example you gave.